# Show Null value using python

Tags: python, bash, shell, wxpython

HI all newbie to coding world. Doing automation project in Python and shell script an GUI using wxPython

My code is:

```
      z = subprocess.Popen(["ps aux | grep 'process1' | grep -v grep"],shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
      connect = z.stdout.readlines()
      connect = "".join(connect)
      if connect is None:  # connect == ' ':
         self.info = wx.MessageBox("Not able to proceed","warning", wx.OK)
      else:

         self.permission = wx.MessageBox("Can enter","warning", wx.OK)
```

but if process1 is not running then also it shows self.permission message box i.e "can enter". What i am doing wrong here.?

Comment: `connect` isn't `None`. Just check `if not connect:`, as empty strings are falsy.

Comment: I'm not sure calling us "newbies" will attract much attention to your question from experienced programmers hanging around... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if not connect:
```

instead of

```
if connect is None.
```

It must work

Answer (score 1):

`connect` cannot be `None` here:

```
  connect = z.stdout.readlines()
  connect = "".join(connect)
  if connect is None:  # connect == ' ':
```

If it was, the line before `if` would throw exception. It can probably be an empty string, so you can change the test as follows:

```
  if not connect:
```